# If I type out the code of this function in the interactive shell it works, but as a function it doesn't, why?

Tags: function, for-loop

Given a string, I want to check if it is a palindrome. A palindrome is a string that reads the same left-to-right and right-to-left. What is wrong with my code? It does not give a true or false when I checkPalindrome('stringhere'). However, when I type in the code in the interactive shell I can a true or false result.

```
def checkPalindrome(inputString):
    inputStringlist = list(inputString)
    for i in range(len(inputStringlist)):
        inputStringlist[len(inputStringlist) - 1 - i] = inputString[i]
    inputStringlist == list(inputString)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return the result from the function. Change the last line of your code to:

```
return inputStringlist == list(inputString)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to optimize this, you can do:

```
def checkPalindrome(inputString):
      if inputString == inputString[::-1]:
            return(True)
      else:
            return(False)
```